# How make [Web Forms for Marketers] module works when using Sitecore Azure?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-azure

Recently, i am working on a project using `Sitecore Azure`.
when creating a web form, we use `Web Forms for Marketers` module provided by `Sitecore`.
It works fine in local environment. but when we publish it to Azure. it dose not work.
Because there is no `database` for web form in Azure.
Has anyone experienced this before, maybe you guys can help me. Thanks

Comment: How do you have WFFM configured in your local interface?  Is WFFM set up to point to a SQL database or is it configured as a local file?

Comment: In my local interface, i set WFFM to point to SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i get it down.

first, you need to create a same database for WFFM as the local one `Sitecore_WebForms` in `SQL Azure`.
Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621790.aspx) tells you how to do it.

second, change the connection string in `forms.config` to point to the database in sql azure.
here is a example.

```
<formsDataProvider type="Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataProviders.WFMDataProvider,Sitecore.Forms.Core">
  <param desc="connection string">Database=Sitecore_WebForms;Data Source=tcp:YOURSERVERNAME.database.windows.net,1433;user id=YOURID;password=YOURPASSWORD;Connect Timeout=60</param>
</formsDataProvider>
```

This is how i fix it. Hope it helps if anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only Web Forms for Marketers (WFFM) 2.4 or higher is compatible with Sitecore Azure module. Additionally, you must use SQL Server version of WFFM database, which must be shared between all WebRole Instances. Please check the details here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/880886

How to add WFFM database in Sitecore Azure and automatically deploy it with entire Sitecore solution read in the following article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/179306

Best Wishes, Oleg